# Equation to output servo values from screen co-ordinates (X/Y) - Python

Tags: python, opencv, screen, coordinate-systems, servo

I’m developing a targeting system where when movement is detected, servos target a
laser pointer to the area of movement. I have a servo for the X axis (pan) and another for the Y axis (tilt).
I need to find a formula that when presented with X and y co-ordinates on the screen
will generate the corresponding pan and tilt values for the servos.

In attached image I have 2 points on the screen, their co-ordinates and the corresponding servo
values. `[X = 42, Y = 146; corresponding servo values are Pan = 35, Tilt = 335] & [X = 542, Y = 307; corresponding servo values are Pan = 276, Tilt = 358]`.

What equation can I use to calculate servo values (pan and tilt) when presented
with any other X and Y coordinates?

I tried using slope `[M=(Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)]` with the 2 X pixel values to get to the Pan value with no luck

Thanks a mill
[image]

Comment: This will be quite a non-linear mapping. The servo is rotating the laser mount, which means you need to know the separation and then use trigonometry to solve for the coordinates. An alternate option is to have a 2-d grid of servo points, shine the laser on your screen for each point, note down the X-Y coordinates of each point, and then use that for interpolating the actual position.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you took to answer my question. I really appreciate it :-) You may have put me on the right track...I'm going to try using linear interpolation to calculate the servo value from the X pixel co-ordinates and then do the same separately for the Y. I have increased the data samples to 12 positions, hopefully it helps. Ill try tackling it tomorrow.

Comment: that will work if you have nicely lined up the laser source with your screen. But to be safer, implementing 2-d interpolation will give better results.